# Moving google maps api code to separate file + jquery

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

This time, i'll go right to the point:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*snip*&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Code.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var map;

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {
                lat: -34.397,
                lng: 150.644
            },
            zoom: 10
        });
    }
});
```

**Result:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.initMap is not a function.
```

Tips?

Also, wonder if this part:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*snip*&callback=initMap">
```

Can be moved to the same code.js file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** Dear friends, this was an awful answer. A really really awful answer.
Well, the solution was fine, the explanation not. This is my strike-through of shame :)

<strike>You don't need to set a  `$(document).ready()` because this tells to the browser to call `initMap();` when the document is ready but you have async and defer in your goolemaps script which means that when you try to execute your initiation you are missing some things.</strike>

**Updated Answer:**
You need just the `initMap()` function in your javascript file.
If you wrap your function inside a `$(document).ready()` function (closures, closures, closures people), then this function(initMap) isn't available outside the `$(document).ready()`.

e.g:
This doesn't work and returns error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunc is not defined'

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        myfunc = function(){
          console.log('myfunc');
        }
     })
     myfunc();
```

This will work:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        myfunc = function(){
            console.log('myfunc');
        }
        myfunc();
    })
```

and this will work:

```
    myfunc = function(){
        console.log('myfunc');
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        myfunc();
    })
```

Why you say? Because of how javascript [scope and closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures) work of course :)

Comment: Does this mean the solution is to remove `async` and `defer` from the maps script?

Comment: please elaborate on what "missing some things" might refer to

Comment: I updated my answer. Thanks for reminding me of this so I could update my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. leave `.....&callback=initMap" async defer></script>` as it is
2. put google's `<script` tag as higher as possible
3. write in your script

   ```
   function initMap() {}; // now it IS a function, lol, and it is in global

   $(() => { // jquery on load
     initMap = function() {
       // your code like...
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {...});
       // and other stuff...
     }
   })
   ```

my complex answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496382/typeerror-window-initmap-is-not-a-function/41610111#41610111)