# TypeError: window.initMap is not a function

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am following this tutorial, basically copy all the code

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

but got an error saying that the initMap function is not a function.
I am using angularjs in my project, could that be causing problems?

I copied the same code into plunker and it works just fine...
What are the possible issues?

Comment: Use the latest version of angular.js and your problem should be solved

Comment: Does your error go away if you remove any containing functions such as JQuery's document.ready?

Comment: if your init map function inside document ready take out from document ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out it has to do with `ng-Route` and the order of loading script
wrote a directive and put the API script on top of everything works.

Comment: I tried this myself and this does not fix the error, just brings the error to the top of the console window.

Answer (score 69):

Actually the error is being generated by the initMap in the Google's api script

```
 <script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

so basically when the Google Map API is loaded then the initMap function is executed. 
If you don't have an initMap function, then the initMap is not a function error is generated.

So basically what you have to do is one of the following options:

1. to create an initMap function
2. replace the callback function with one of your own that created for the same purpose but named it something else
3. replace the `&callback=angular.noop` if you just want an empty function() (only if you use angular)

Comment: Eventough function initMap exists, it keeps saying the same thing

Comment: is your initMap function loaded prior the callback event?
Could you provide the error or how you define the function?

Hint: this function must be global, or if it is a property of an object, you have to update the callback function in  the gmap link to point to this specific property and make sure that the object is instantiated before the callback event.

Comment: Why did i get a negative score because of this comment ? 

Problem was because of wordpress' wysiwyg html editor.

It was inserting random <p> tags for the empty lines in js code inserted. i made the js code one line, problem gone.

Comment: (first one solve. thanks)-->    

window.initMap = function() {};

Comment: I was having the same issue as OP, and i was following the same tutorial as well as a few others. My problem was it was randomly occuring, once every 10 times i loaded it, InitMap was not a function. Your comment actually made me notice that the JS was called after the Map API, so it would make sense that the occasionally the API would finish before the JS and then call the function in the JS which was not loaded yet, hence Not existing (not a function). Moving the JS above the API call and 50 reloads later, still no error.

Comment: This API call must happen after the file in which `initMap` has loaded. So in your script list in your html file, put this below the file in which you placed `initMap`.

Comment: is this function name fixed? i have added callback=InitializeMap instead, but its not working

Comment: It looks like without the following code "window.initMap = initMap;"   It works  fine. Can anybody explain do I need that line?

Answer (score 55):

My explanation of this problem:

The `.....&callback=initMap" async defer></script>` makes that script load async (in parallel with DOM) and after load - execute initMap function. ***NOTICE that initMap() in global scope!*** We can't declare our initMap() *after* google's script because it should already be at the moment of finish async load. Although we can't load our script *before* this, because we need google's function to execute ours.  This is like vicious circle.

## Three solutions:

#### 1'st and worst: make google's script load synchronously

1. remove `async defer`
2. remove `&callback=initMap` in `src` attribute
3. put `<script` tag with your code after google's script

#### 2'nd and best: just do this =)

1. leave `.....&callback=initMap" async defer></script>` as is
2. and put google's `<script` tag after your script
3. write in your script

   ```
   function initMap() {} // now it IS a function and it is in global

   $(() => {
     initMap = function() {
       // your code like...
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {/*your code*/});
       // and other stuff...
     }
   })
   ```

   this allow you *load* google's script async and *run* yours just after that

#### 3'rd and strange: it will work... some times =)

3. do same but simply write in global scope

   ```
   function initMap() {
     // your code
   }
   ```

   and if you write it in global scope, that will work regardless of what
   which code loads faster, your (sync) or google's (async). More often your wins

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked! Can you please elaborate your second option? I'm new to JQuery. How does $(() => { }), make sure the method runs after the maps is loaded ? Is it like a shorthand for document.ready?

Comment: I've added #2 verbatim, and I'm receiving this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`.

From this line:
`var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {...});`

What's causing that error?

Comment: inside {...} you should put your code, not "..." I just wrote that to point that there should be some code. Sorry, I'll change it to comment.

Comment: Why is the first solution worse? In my case, i don't want to call the map on page load. I want to show it when a specific element is clicked. And this element is loaded dynamically from WebSQL, therefore, i don't even know when the element will be loaded, and i'm pretty sure google script will load faster. In that case, the best solution should be to remove the callback, and call the map when my element is clicked, right?

Comment: @IsraelObanijesu , I would do things like -> user click element -> show loader -> load google map -> initialize google map -> hide loader. So I would not even load google map on page load whether sync or async.

Comment: @AndreyKudriavtsev Please, can you show an example of that, the part of loading google map after showing the loader, i can't picture how that would be done.  I had a recent idea which was to use the callback method you specified, load and initialize the map with random location data, but hide it, then when the element is clicked, display the map with appropriate location data. I'm trying to choose the most efficient method for my app.

Answer (score 16):

I have been struggling for several days with this very popular in the last few months issue - "initMap is not a function".

Those two threads helped me:

1. [How to make a callback to Google Maps init in separate files of a web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627259/how-to-make-a-callback-to-google-maps-init-in-separate-files-of-a-web-app?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Defer attribute doesn't work with Google Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033329/defer-attribute-doesnt-work-with-google-maps-api?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Why does the map open sometimes and sometimes not. It depends on several factors like speed of connection, environment, etc. Because the initialization function sometimes runs after the google maps API kicks in, that's why the map is not displayed and the browser console throws an error. For me removing only the async attribute fixed the issue. The defer attribute stays.

If async is present: The script is executed asynchronously with the rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page continues the parsing)
If async is not present and defer is present: The script is executed when the page has finished parsing
If neither async or defer is present: The script is fetched and executed immediately, before the browser continues parsing the page
Source - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Hope that helps. Cheers.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Viktor!

Comment: Using only defer (after remove "async"), it works. Thank you.

Comment: Works after removing "async"

Answer (score 15):

Removing `=initMap` worked for me:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback"></script>
```

Comment: I think if initMap will be omitted, the map will not load in the first load?

Comment: How did you create the map or called your callback respectively?

Comment: This works perfectly with Angular since the problem is just the error and everything else works without any initMap function

Comment: @KickButtowski If the initMap function is called on a component (in Angular) then the callback isn't needed in the script tag in index.html. The error appears when the application loads and doesn't find initMap(), but on navigating to a route containing a map the typescript file calls initMap(), which it will do anyway to set coordinates an d options. My map was working (remember to specify a height in CSS!) but I was still getting this error as soon as the app started. Removing the callback removed the error, and the maps work as expected.

Comment: Also using angular, I removed the initMap from the script in my index.html and create initMap at the component level. We have many maps across a large application and it makes more sense to call it when the user navigates to each page, and all the maps have different data etc.

Answer (score 10):

The problem has to do with the async attribute in the script tag. The Callback Function is trying to call "initMap()" when it doesn't really exists by the time the request finished.

To solve this I placed the Goole Maps Api Script bellow the script where my initMap function was declared.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 9):

This may seem obvious but just in case: If someone placed the JS code inside $(document).ready like this:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
       ... Google Maps JS code ...
      }
```

Then that's the problem because using `async` `defer` when loading the Google Maps API library, it will load asynchronously, and when it finishes loading, will look for the callback function, which needs to be available by then.

So, you just need to put the code *outside* **$(document).ready**, and:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

at the very bottom, so your page loads FAST :-)

Comment: your answer is just the answer that makes sense. thank you. If you can explain what defer does, It will be awesome. :)

Answer (score 5):

Solved by adding

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXX&callback=initMap">
    <!--
        https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation
    -->
</script>
```

At the beginning of the same file which contains the rest of the code with `function initMap()`. It's definitely not the best solution, but it works..

But I think that if you would transform `function initMap()` to something like `var=initMap()` and then `$(function () ...` it would work too.

Comment: What’s the actual point? Having an HTML comment inside the script element? Putting selfsame at the beginning?

Answer (score 4):

I am using React and I had mentioned &callback=initMap in the script as below

```
<script 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

then is just removed the `&callback=initMap` part now there is no such error as window.initMap is not a function in the console.

Comment: but how did you load the map if that function never executes?

Comment: @sanan ali You can write a function like `function initMap() { //do something}`.  And then call the function like this `window.initMap = initMap();`.

Answer (score 4):

your call back method probably is not globally accessible. in my case I'd used transpoiled ES6 codes via webpack which caused my callback method not being global anymore.

Try to attach your callback method explicitly to `window` like so right after your callback method declaration and see the result

```
window.initMap = initMap;
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

For me the main difference was the declaration of the function....

INSTEAD OF

```
function initMap() {
    ...
}
```

THIS WORKED

```
window.initMap = function () {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create initMap method between "" tag or load javascript file before call google api.

```html
<script src="Scripts/main.js"></script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=abcde&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your html body (taken from the official angular.js website):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I believe that you were using some older angular.js files since you don't have any issues in plunker and therefore you got the specified error.

Answer (score 2):

This is the top result when you Google 'initMap function is not a function' so although there are a lot of answers already, I will make it very clear for the rookies like me what is happening.

To load a Google Map your page need 3 things:

1. A `<div id="map"></div>`
2. Load the Google Map javascript.
3. A function to initiate the map.

## The div (easy)

The div is easy. The Google Map Javascript is easy but there is a catch.

## Load Google Maps Javascript

```
<script
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOURKEY&callback=initMap"
  defer
></script>
```

There are two important parts of this script. **defer**, and the **callback=initMap**

First let's talk about defer. The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML document has been parsed. This makes sure your div is loaded and ready to be used by the javascript. However, does not mean that the Google Maps Javascript will load after *your* Javascript, and that is why the error happens sometimes.

## The init function

You need to call a function to run the code that sets up the Google Map. The callback makes it easy because once the Google Maps code loads, it will call a function you tell it to load the map.

I'll repeat that because it is important. The **callback=initMap** is calling the initMap function in *your* code.

So if your code hasn't loaded by the time the Google Maps javascript loads, it will call `initMap` but you get the error because it doesn't know what initMap is because your code, where you define initMap hasn't loaded yet.

This can happen seemingly randomly as network times vary. Sometimes you code loads first, and it works. Sometimes your code doesn't load first and Google Maps code loads first and you get the error.

## Solution

There are a lot of solutions, but the one that I like is don't set a callback, and init the Map yourself after you know everything is loaded.

This way, we can load Google Maps Javascript async, which is faster since it loads in a separate process and doesn't wait for anything.

```
<script async
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEY">
</script>
```

Notice how there is no callback set. So Google Map Javascript will not automatically call my init function, I have to call it when I know everything is ready.

We can do that with a window load event listener.

```
window.addEventListener("load", docReady);

function docReady() {
    initMap();
}
```

The window load event fires after *everything including Javascript* has loaded.

Of course this might slow the page down as it has to load everything, including images, and then it will fire and initialize the map, *but it ensures it will work every time.*

As you learn more, you will learn other ways to make sure things load in the correct order. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error. The answers here helped me figure out what to do.

index.html

```
 <!--The div element for the map -->
 <div id="map"></div>

<!--The link to external javascript file that has initMap() function-->
 <script src="main.js">

<!--Google api, this calls initMap() function-->
 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEYWY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

main.js
// This gives error

```
// The initMap function has not been executed
const initMap = () => {
const mapDisplayElement = document.getElementById('map');
  // The address is Uluru
const address = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
  // The zoom property specifies the zoom level for the map. Zoom: 0 is the lowest zoom,and displays the entire earth.
const map = new google.maps.Map(mapDisplayElement, { zoom: 4, center: address });
const marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: address, map });
};
```

The answers here helped me figure out a solution.
I used an immediately invoked the function ([IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) )  to work around it.

The error is as at the time of calling the google maps api the initMap() function has not executed.

main.js
// This works

```
const mapDisplayElement = document.getElementById('map');
// The address is Uluru
// Run the initMap() function imidiately, 
(initMap = () => {
  const address = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
  // The zoom property specifies the zoom level for the map. Zoom: 0 is the lowest zoom,and displays the entire earth.
  const map = new google.maps.Map(mapDisplayElement, { zoom: 4, center: address });
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: address, map });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

What actually worked for me was:

1. In the HTML file, I removed the `async` attribute from the `<script>` tag.
2. In the JavaScript file, I double-checked that the function was outside the `$(document).ready` function.

Answer (score 0):

Could be your initMap function is in a $(document).ready function. If it is then it won't work, it has to be outside of any other functions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @DB.Null's answer, I used `Function.prototype` as no-op (no-operation) function on #3 instead of `angular.noop` (I don't have angular in my project).

So this...

`<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&callback=Function.prototype" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a formatting issue earlier on, so the error was a consequence of something else.  My server was rendering the lat/lon values with commas instead of periods, because of different regional settings.

Comment: Interesting. How did you find out?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the callback of "initMap" from the script tag and placed the callback in my JavaScript file.

`<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEYWY&callback=initMap"></script>`

was changed to

`<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEYWY"></script>`

So the first JS tag is mine.

`<script async type=module src="js/app.js"></script>`
`<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEYWY"></script>`

I called the initMap function from within my JS file by adding the following to my app.js file.

`initMap();`

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me:

```
this.initMap = () => {};
```

...

```
src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had to load the Map on my Wordpress website and the problem was that the Google's api script was loading before the initMap(). Therefore, I solved the problem with a delay:

```php
<script>
function initMap() {
     // Your Javascript Codes for the map
     ...
}

<?php
// Delay for 5 seconds
sleep(5);
?>

</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEYWY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Don't do this. You block the thread. Better ways to handle this.