# Google Maps Javascript autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

quite new to Javascript and have been on this problem for ages. I am trying to use Google Maps Javascript API to validate an address in a form and I have no idea why it is not working. I have inserted the API reference.
I am using Angular Material (if you were wondering about the md stuff)

HTML

```
<md-input-container>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
</md-input-container>
```

Javascript

```
function initMap() {
    var input = (document.getElementById('pac-input'));
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
};
```

I know the answer must be super easy but you would be helping me a lot!

Comment: What doesn't work? Any error? Do you actually call `initMap()` anywhere?

Comment: It doesn't autocomplete anything. To the second question - I guess I am not.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine! [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GVdK6/81/) Just call the `initMap();`

Comment: Thanks Stergios - It's an Angular application and when I open the view itself, it works (and your fiddle does too) but it doesnt work in my index.html when I open it - Very strange!

Comment: Do you have any error in console? Perhaps `google is not defined`?

Comment: This is the error I get in Safari inspect TypeError: window.initMap is not a function. (In 'window.initMap()', 'window.initMap' is undefined)

Comment: @Nicholas you will find the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496382/typeerror-window-initmap-is-not-a-function . I dont know angular but by reading the answers in the link i think error is with `callback function`.