# Using PHP variables in Google Maps Directions API

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps, google-api

I am using the code provided by Google showing their Google Maps Directions API. I have manually changed the origin and destination values and it works perfectly. However when trying to replace the origin and destination values with PHP variables the map won't load.

Here's my code, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <body>

  <?php
  $start = "Leeds";
  $end = "Nottingham";
  ?>
```

```
     <div id="right-panel"></div>


   <script type="text/javascript">

     var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom:7,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
     directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));


     var request = {
       origin: <?php echo $start; ?>,
       destination: <?php echo $end; ?> ,
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
     };

     directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       }
     });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're missing quotes around the PHP. Try this.
When you use echo in PHP,

```
$Example = "hey";
```

The PHP will only echo whats inside the quotes. 
So in your JavaScript you have to add them manually or your result is

```
  origin: Start,
  destination: End
```

It needs to be

```
 origin: 'Start',
  destination: 'End'
```

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

     var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom:7,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
     directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));


     var request = {
       origin:'<?php echo $start; ?>',
       destination:'<?php echo $end; ?>' ,
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
     };

     directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       }
     });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quote looks like the right answer here. `<?= "leeds"; ?>` will output `leeds` and JavaScript expects the value in an object array to be quoted like this `'leeds'`. The quotes help JavaScript understand spaces, too. For example `origin: New York` would break JavaScript whereas `origin: 'New York'` is valid.

Comment: Just added that

Comment: Just tried adding quotes to the PHP, still does not seem to load the map.

Comment: @BradWaterhouse If you are testing your page within a web browser try opening the JavaScript console then refreshing the page. Is there a warning or error printed there related to the Google Maps API? That would help diagnose your problem. On Firefox, Chrome, and IE press F12 to open the console.

Also, "just tried adding quotes to the PHP": does this mean you added single quotes to the PHP code? Your origin line should look like this: `origin: '<?php echo $start; ?>',` and not this `origin: <?php echo '$start'; ?>,` Lastly, are $start and $end actually printing in the page source?

Comment: After looking in the console log, it doesn't seem to be reading "initmap" as a function.

Comment: And my origin and destination lines of code correctly formatted now.

Comment: Okay. Then your code is good and it's the Google API that is throwing that error :) Try searching for `Google Maps API init not a function`. I found this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496382/typeerror-window-initmap-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Did you get it ?