# React Google maps API initMap not a function, no packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

Receiving below error that initMap is not a function. I was trying not to use any extra packages to load this script asynchronously or for Google Maps API. 
I was trying to just console log initMap to see when the script is loaded, but I am still getting the error that it is not a function. I can move this function outside of componentDidMount or even outside of the App component, but the error is the same.

My guess is it has something to do with the fact that the script is getting loaded through document.createElement, but the initMap function is not, as when I look at other examples of Google Maps API it shows both the API URL and the initMap functoin on the index.html page.

Is this assumption correct? Is there a way to easily asynchronously load the function as a script or the Google Maps API in React without using any of the other packages?

```
Uncaught Ib {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Ib (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…ZVRgF122wCkVf4P67Y&v=3.32&callback=initMap:163:56"}
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();

import React, {
  Component
} from 'react'
import './App.css'
let map;

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {

    function initMap() {
      console.log('loaded')
    }

    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.async = true
    script.defer = true
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={myAPIkey}=3.32&callback=initMap"
    document.head.appendChild(script)
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div > {
        this.map
      } <
      div style = {
        {
          width: 500,
          height: 500
        }
      }
      id = "map" / >
      <
      /div>
    )
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  width: 500;
  height: 500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <title>React Map</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `callback=initMap` is looking for a function `initMap` on `window`. `initMap` of your `App` component is not attached to `window` and therefore will not be seen/accessible by the script callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed as Alexander Staroselsky noticed callback=initMap is looking for a function initMap on window. You should either make initMap function global or assign the initMap function inside the class to a variable on window object like this:

```
window.initMap = this.initMap.bind(this);
```

Comment: This worked for me, I also found this listed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496382/typeerror-window-initmap-is-not-a-function

Comment: You could also remove the `callback=initMap` query parameter from `src` URL in the script tag that you use to load the googleMaps script